# peek and element in Java's LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list

What is the difference between peek and element in Java's LinkedList?

Here is what the Oracle Java Documentation page describes them to be, but they do not explain the difference.

> public E peek()
> Retrieves, but does not remove, the head (first element) of this list.
> Specified by:
> peek in interface Deque<E>
> Specified by:
> peek in interface Queue<E>
> Returns:
> the head of this list, or null if this list is empty
> Since:
> 1.5
>
> public E element()
> Retrieves, but does not remove, the head (first element) of this list.
> Specified by:
> element in interface Deque<E>
> Specified by:
> element in interface Queue<E>
> Returns:
> the head of this list
> Throws:
> NoSuchElementException - if this list is empty
> Since:
> 1.5

Is the difference just that one throws and exception and another returns null in case our list is empty?

Comment: Yes. That is the contract of peek and element

Comment: Look at the returns/throws clauses of either, which describes the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [the documentation of `Queue`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Queue.html), we find the following table:

> Summary of Queue methods
>
> |  | *Throws Exception* | *Returns special value* |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Insert | [`add(e)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Queue.html#add(E)) | [`offer(e)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Queue.html#offer(E)) |
> | Remove | [`remove()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Queue.html#remove()) | [`poll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Queue.html#poll()) |
> | Examine | [`element()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Queue.html#element()) | [`peek()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Queue.html#peek()) |

So as we can see, the difference is that [`element()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Queue.html#element()) may throw a [`NoSuchElementException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html), while [`peek()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Queue.html#peek()) does not.

Comment: Great. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Which was also specified in the Javadoc the OP quoted (_"Returns: the head of this list, or **null if this list is empty**"_ vs _"Returns: the head of this list **Throws: NoSuchElementException - if this list is empty**"_

Comment: @MarkRotteveel What about peek and peekfirst?

Comment: @potatomotato They are the same (_"The methods inherited from the Queue interface are precisely equivalent to Deque methods as indicated in the following table:"_ as documented in [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Deque.html)). `peek()` is defined in `Queue`, while `peekFirst()` is defined in `Deque`, to have clear named pairs `peekFirst()` and `peekLast()`, as that reduces the mental overhead for programmers using it. You may want to get in the habit of carefully reading the Javadoc, because these things are usually explicitly mentioned.